# How to get the payload property from bean validation annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, bean-validation

I have a class with validation annotations on my properties, like this one:

```
@NotNull(payload = INVALID_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION.class)
@Size(min = 1, max = 255, payload = INVALID_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION_LENGHT.class)
private String description;
```

Then I have a @ControllerAdvice to handle validation exceptions.

```
@ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> methodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
```

When one or more validation annotation fail, the exception handler is triggered as expected.

In order to get the payload property from the annotations, I am iterating over the fields with validation errors, then over the annotations and only then comparing the annotation name with the FieldError code. With the annotation in hands I can access the payload.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to get the payload or the annotation which triggered the exception, as there is for the message property (exception.getMessage()).

Comment: Same problem here - how to get ConstraintViolationException instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your starting point is a `ConstraintViolationException` you are getting the set of `ConstraintViolation` instances via `getConstraintViolations()`.

Each `ConstraintViolation` then has a `getConstraintDescriptor()`, which gives you metadata about the failing constraints. Once you have the `ConstraintDescriptor` you just call `getPayload()`.

Comment: Thank you @Hardy, the problem is the starting point is MethodArgumentNotValidException as it's not performing validations by code, it is relying in annotations.

Comment: Thanks. And `getPayload()` returns?? iterator of objects? classes? for parsing? casting?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I think I might help others.

To get payload from MethodArgumentNotValidException

```
var constraintViolation = exception.getBindingResult()
                        .getAllErrors().get(0).unwrap(ConstraintViolation.class);
        
     // Get dynamic payload
    var payload = (Payload) ((ConstraintViolationImpl)
                        constraintViolation).getDynamicPayload(ValidationExceptionPayload.class);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can not believe i could figure it out by myself!

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve dynamic payload from **MethodArgumentNotValidException**:

```
List<ClassTypeDynamicPayload> allDynamicPayloadObjects = exception
    .getBindingResult()
    .getAllErrors()
    .stream()
    .map(validationFieldError -> validationFieldError.unwrap(ConstraintViolationImpl.class))
    .map(constraintViolation -> constraintViolation.getDynamicPayload(ClassTypeDynamicPayload.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

---

To retrieve `ConstraintViolation` (s) out of **ConstraintViolationException** use:

```
constraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations();
```

To get dynamic payload out of a `ConstraintViolation`:

```
(ClassToMap) ((ConstraintViolationImpl) constraintViolation).getDynamicPayload(ClassToMap.class))
```

Comment: The author said he [does not have access to a ConstraintViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343617/how-to-get-the-payload-property-from-bean-validation-annotation#comment60424726_36374457)

Comment: This adds up to the answer made by @Hardy. Some might find it helpful.